# Google Analytics и создание аудиторий (справка, которая врёт)

Tags: веб-программирование, google-analytics, аналитика

Собственно вопрос:

Была создана аудитория "Все пользователи" (источник - представлении "Основное" до которого есть доступ с почты example1@gmail.com), опубликована в акк ads (акк ads привязан к почте example2@gmail.com, которая не имеет доступа до представления "Основное", до других представлений доступ имеет)

Т.к. аудитории создаются на ур-не ресурса проблем вызвать данный факт не должен.

В справке написано, что "При создании аудитории в нее добавляются данные за последние 30 дней (или меньше, если данные доступны за более короткий период), поэтому список можно использовать сразу." ( https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611404?hl=ru )

По факту, мы видим, что после создания аудитории прошло больше недели, но кол-во пользователей, включенных в аудиторию ± 4,5 тыс., а не 75 тыс., как должно быть (если смотреть кол-во поль-лей за последние 30 дней). Собственно, есть предположение, что она начала собираться с момента публикации (а справка лукавит).

Не возникало бы сомнений по поводу справки, если бы не встречался с несостыковками до этого. Например, справка гласит, что если указать период ретроспективного обзора 30 дней, то при создании аудитории в аудиторию добавятся поль-ли, которые соответствуют критериям (скрин > http://prntscr.com/nlj7u2 , справка > [https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015314?hl=ru](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015314?hl=ru%C2%A0) )

По факту же поль-ли, которые попадают под критерии, добавятся в аудиторию только после того как еще раз зайдут на сайт после создании аудитории ( пруф из GA > http://prntscr.com/nljadg )

Собственно, поэтому вопрос - может ли быть такое, что при создании аудитории "Все пользователи" GA "смотрит" назад на 30 дней, выделяет тех пользователей, которые соответствуют критериям, но добавляет их в аудиторию только после того, как они инициируют новый сеанс на сайте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> при создании аудитории "Все пользователи" GA "смотрит" назад на 30 дней, выделяет тех пользователей, которые соответствуют критериям, но добавляет их в аудиторию только после того, как они инициируют новый сеанс на сайте

Так и есть.

Если [вчитаться](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2611404?hl=ru):

> **Все пользователи**. Все пользователи вашего сайта или приложения, у которых уже есть необходимые файлы cookie или идентификаторы мобильной рекламы.

Слова "уже есть необходимые файлы" говорят о том, что нужно перезайти.